# Remove required validation only for 1 page

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

How can I remove the required field only for 1 page? I'm using Razor pages. I want the same validation for my password, username, etc., but without the required validation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For conditional required attribute , you could customize `RequiredIfTrue` attribute like below:

*RequiredIfTrueAttribute*

```
 public class RequiredIfTrueAttribute : ValidationAttribute, IClientModelValidator
{
    private string PropertyName { get; set; }

    public RequiredIfTrueAttribute(string propertyName)
    {
        PropertyName = propertyName;
        ErrorMessage = "The {0} field is required."; //used if error message is not set on attribute itself
    }

    protected override ValidationResult IsValid(object value, ValidationContext context)
    {
        object instance = context.ObjectInstance;
        Type type = instance.GetType();

        bool.TryParse(type.GetProperty(PropertyName).GetValue(instance)?.ToString(), out bool propertyValue);

        if (propertyValue && (value == null || string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(value.ToString())))
        {
            return new ValidationResult(ErrorMessage);
        }

        return ValidationResult.Success;
    }

    public void AddValidation(ClientModelValidationContext context)
    {
        object isrequired;
        var viewContext = context.ActionContext as ViewContext;
        viewContext.ViewData.TryGetValue(PropertyName, out isrequired);
       if ((bool)isrequired)
        {
            MergeAttribute(context.Attributes, "data-val", "true");
            var errorMessage = FormatErrorMessage(context.ModelMetadata.GetDisplayName());
            MergeAttribute(context.Attributes, "data-val-requirediftrue", errorMessage);
        }

    }

    private bool MergeAttribute(IDictionary<string, string> attributes, string key, string value)
    {
        if (attributes.ContainsKey(key))
        {
            return false;
        }
        attributes.Add(key, value);
        return true;
    }
}
```

*Model*

```
public class User
{
    public bool IsRequired { get; set; }

    [RequiredIfTrue("IsRequired")]
    [StringLength(6)]
    public string UserName { get; set; }

    [RequiredIfTrue("IsRequired")]

    [StringLength(100, ErrorMessage = "The {0} must be at least {2} and at max {1} characters long.", MinimumLength = 6)]
    public string Password { get; set; }

    public int Age { get; set; }
}
```

*PageModel*

```
public class UserProfile1Model : PageModel
{
    [BindProperty]
    public User User { get; set; }
    public void OnGet()
    {
        User = new User { IsRequired = true };
    }

    public async Task<IActionResult> OnPost()
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            return RedirectToPage(nameof(Index));
        }
        return Page();
    }
}
```

*Page* , save the IsRequired value into ViewData to judge if  adding verification in `AddValidation` method

```
@page
@model RazorPages3_1.UserProfile1Model
@{
  ViewData["Title"] = "UserProfile1";
  ViewData["IsRequired"] = Model.User.IsRequired;
}
<form id="frm" method="post">
<div asp-validation-summary="ModelOnly" class="text-danger"></div>
<div class="form-group">
    <label asp-for="User.UserName" class="control-label"></label>
    <input asp-for="User.UserName" class="form-control" />
    <span asp-validation-for="User.UserName" class="text-danger"></span>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    <label asp-for="User.Password" class="control-label"></label>
    <input asp-for="User.Password" class="form-control" />
    <span asp-validation-for="User.Password" class="text-danger"></span>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    <label asp-for="User.Age" class="control-label"></label>
    <input asp-for="User.Age" class="form-control" />
    <span asp-validation-for="User.Age" class="text-danger"></span>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="Create" />
</div>
</form>

@section Scripts
{
  @{ await Html.RenderPartialAsync("_ValidationScriptsPartial");}

}
```

*Custom client-side validation*, requiredIftrue.validation.js

```
 $.validator.addMethod("requirediftrue",
    function (value, element, parameters) {
        return value !== "" && value != null;
    }
);

$.validator.unobtrusive.adapters.addBool('requirediftrue');
```

add it in _ValidationScriptsPartial.cshtml

```
<script src="~/lib/jquery-validation/dist/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/lib/jquery-validation-unobtrusive/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js"></script>

<script src="~/lib/requiredIftrue/requiredIftrue.validation.js"></script>
```

Result
[image]